# How do I update value in field with time returned from a timer function Kendo Mobile UI

Tags: jquery, mobile, binding, timer, kendo-ui

I have a view which contains some timing data.
I am running a javascript timer function which works out elased seconds between the start and stop events.

I wish to update my view with the elapsed seconds and to sync this time to the record store as offilineData.

My view template is this:

```
<!-- TaskTime Template -->
<script id="taskTimeTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  # var eSecs = ElapsedSeconds #
  # ElapsedTime = (eSecs / 3600).toFixed() +'h'+ ('0'+eSecs % 60).slice(-2)+'m'; #
  <h2 id="#:Guid#"><i class="icon-time"></i> #: Description #</h2>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" style="font-size:90%;">            
    <p>Project ID: #: ParentId #</p>
    <p>TaskID #:Id#</p>
    <p>Time spent to date: #: ElapsedSeconds #</p>
  </ul>
</script>
```

My timer function is run and stopped by this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Start button */
    $('#start').click(function(e){
      $('#timerButtonGroup').attr('data-index', 1);
      startTime = new Date().getTime();
       timer();
       closeSheet();
    });
    /* Stop button */
    $('#stop').click(function(e){
      $('#timerButtonGroup').attr('data-index', 2);
      endTime = new Date().getTime();
      tElapsedTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
       clearTimeout(t);
       closeSheet();
    });
});
```

I am somewhat new to Kendo Mobile UI and am at a loss as to how to tie the time I get from the timer to the record I need to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Start button */
    $('#start').click(function(e){
      $('#timerButtonGroup').attr('data-index', 1);
      window.tmp.startTime = new Date().getTime();
       timer();
       closeSheet();
    });
    /* Stop button */
    $('#stop').click(function(e){
      $('#timerButtonGroup').attr('data-index', 2);
      endTime = new Date().getTime();
      tElapsedTime = (endTime - window.tmp.startTime)/1000;
       clearTimeout(t);
       closeSheet();
      console.log(endTime);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Legendary.
I am actually ok with the timer part. tElapsedTime is being worked out correctly.  My aim now, is to send that (or bind it) to the value in the Kendo view/template, so that I can sync() to the localDataStore.

Unfortunately, Kendo documentation has been written by the Kendo team and is not very good at explaining use-cases. (They really need to employ a technical documentation person).

Anyway, that is the issue I am having; how to bind the time produced by that function to the time in the Kendo view.  Maybe I should rephrase my initial question and post again?